# How does this Permitted character check work?

Tags: vb.net

Don't understand what this code does

```
Dim strAllowedChars As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz() -+ "

If Len(TxtFirstName.Text) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    For i = 0 To Len(TxtFirstName.Text) - 1
        If InStr(1, strAllowedChars, TxtFirstName.Text(i)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Number Detected")
            TxtFirstName.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Don't understand what the code actually works

Comment: This code parses the content of a TextBox.Text char by char. If the current symbol is not included in the control list of symbols, then it's (allegedly) a number. It messages the detection of a number and exits the loop/sub. Old code. See [Char.IsNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber)

Comment: I don't mean that these control lists are outdated. They're not. It depends on what they're used for.

Comment: If you want to know whether a `String` contains any digits then use `myString.Any(Function(ch) Char.IsDigit(ch))`.  If you want to know if it's all digits then call `All` instead of `Any`. If you want to know it is a valid representation of a number then call the appropriate `TryParse` method. Also, an application developer should not be calling `Focus`. As the documentation clearly states, `Select` is how you focus a control in a WinForms app.